# DataTables combine FooterCallback and select filtering

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function, datatables

Good evening.

I had some problems combining two DataTables functions `(see title)`.

This `(FooterCallback)` to display the sum of a column with numeric values:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#pr_table').DataTable( {
    "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        var api = this.api(), data;

        // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
        var intVal = function ( i ) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
                i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                typeof i === 'number' ?
                    i : 0;
        };

        // Total over all pages
        total = api
            .column( 4 )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );

        // Total over this page
        pageTotal = api
            .column( 4, { page: 'current'} )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );

        // Update footer
        $( api.column( 4 ).footer() ).html(
            'cub.m'+pageTotal +' ( cub.m'+ total +' total)'
        );
    }
  } );
} );
```

With this `(select filtering)`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#pr_table').DataTable( {
    "initComplete": function () {
        var api = this.api();

        api.columns().indexes().flatten().each( function ( i ) {
            var column = api.column( i );
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.header()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    }

  } );
} );
```

If I use only one of the functions in my script, everything is working just fine. But trying to combine them results in DataTables failing to initialize at all (just raw html table shows up).
I am relatively unfamiliar with javascript this advanced, so it would help me if someone would give me an example of the script with a little explanation how to use multiple functions in one initialization.